# Django-filter How to change placeholder to replace [invalid name]?

Tags: python, django, django-filters

I create a filter to search in multiple fields (I must have only one search field) like this :

class myFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    full_search = django_filters.CharFilter(name='full_search', method='search_by_full_search')

```
def search_by_full_search(self, qs, name, value):
    for term in value.split():
        qs = qs.filter(Q(serial__icontains=term) | Q(id__icontains=term) | Q(name__icontains=term))
    return qs

class Meta:
    model = myModel
    fields = ['full_search', ]
```

But in html, the placeholder shows my trickery !

```
<input type="text" name="full_search" class="form-control" placeholder="[invalid name]" title="" id="id_full_search">
```

Is it possible to change by something else ?

Answer (score 15):

I know this has been asked a while ago, but just solved a similar problem in a project, so posting it here to help out if anyone else faces this issue.

```
full_search = django_filters.CharFilter(method='search_by_full_search', label='Recherche') # change label field to reflect what the filter name should be

class Meta:
   model = myModel
   fields = ['full_search', ]

def search_by_full_search(self, qs, name, value):
    for term in value.split():
      qs = qs.filter(Q(serial__icontains=term) | Q(id__icontains=term) | 
      Q(name__icontains=term))
    return qs
```

[image: This is how the filter will appear in the browseable API]

Answer (score 1):

Finally I did this with JQuery :

```
$('#id_full_search').attr("placeholder", "Recherche")
```